# Create Word Search game in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, wordsearch

i want to create a Word Search game using Visual Basic? I've already started it by creating grids (10x10). However, I do not know how to properly insert the words that the user will search for.

Here's a look at what I did as well as the codes.[10x10 grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMVgW.png)

as you can I see, I created the grid using the Paint Event handler.

I have a text file containing all the words that the user will search. Using VB I open and read all the lines and put the words in an array (not seen in the picture).

I want the words to be inserted in the grid randomly. But I do not know how to?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The visual grid is a bit of a distraction at this stage. concentrate on getting a list of strings into an nxn two-dimensional string array. I would write a sub which, given a list of words and a dimension, returns a filled-in array (if possible).

A natural choice is a backtracking algorithm, which seeks to randomly place words into a partially filled array. For each new word, generate the collection of all valid locations and then randomly pick one of those locations. If there are no valid locations -- backtrack, removing the most recently placed word and placing it somewhere else. It might help to first sort the list of words to be placed in order of decreasing length, since it will be easier to place smaller words into a partially-filled in array than larger words. Placing the larger words when there are less constraints will thus lessen the amount of back-tracking needed.

When all of the words have been placed, fill in the rest of the array randomly.

Comment: Thank you. However, I have no idea how to do backtracking algorithm. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public bytPuzzle() As Byte
Public bytPuzzleKey() As Byte

Public lngPos() As Long
Public lngDir(7) As Long

Public lngW(25) As Long ' 25
Public lngSumW As Long

Public Sub InitbytPuzzle(ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer)
   
    Dim i As Long

    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
        
    Dim sz As Long
     
    sz& = (w + 1) * h
    
    ReDim bytPuzzle(sz& - 1)
    ReDim bytPuzzleKey(sz& - 1)
    
    For i& = 0 To (sz& - 1)
        bytPuzzle(i) = 32
        bytPuzzleKey(i) = 32
    Next i&
    
    For i& = w To (sz& - 1) Step (w + 1)
        bytPuzzle(i&) = 0 'prevents breaking on edges
        bytPuzzleKey(i&) = 0
    Next i
    
    lngDir(0) = -w - 1 'up
    lngDir(1) = -w 'upright
    lngDir(2) = 1 'right
    lngDir(3) = w + 2 'downright
    lngDir(4) = w + 1 'down
    lngDir(5) = w 'downleft
    lngDir(6) = -1 'left
    lngDir(7) = -w - 2 'upleft
    
    ReDim lngPos(w * h - 1)

    For i& = 0 To (sz& - 1)
    
        'insert lngPos in random order
        If (bytPuzzle(i&) = 32) Or (bytPuzzleKey(i&) = 32) Then
        
            k& = (Int(Rnd * (j& + 1)))
            
            lngPos(j&) = (lngPos(k&))
            lngPos(k&) = (i&)
            
            j& = (j& + 1)
            
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub

Public Function AddWord(ByVal s As String) As Boolean

    Dim x As Long
    Dim d As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    If Len(s) = 0 Then
    
        AddWord = True
        
        Exit Function
        
    End If

    dc& = Int(Rnd * 2) ' 8

    For p& = 0 To UBound(lngPos&)
    
        x& = lngPos(p&)
        
        For d& = 0 To UBound(lngDir&)

            a& = lngDir(d& Xor dc&)
            
            If (FitPuzzle(s$, x&, a&) = True) Then
            
                Call PlacePuzzlePiece(s$, x&, a&)
                
                AddWord = True
                
                Exit Function
                
            End If
            
        Next d&
        
    Next p&
    
    AddWord = False
    
End Function

Public Function FitPuzzle(s As String, ByVal x As Long, ByVal a As Long) As Boolean

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For i& = 1 To Len(s$)
    
        c& = Asc(Mid(s$, i&, 1))
        
        If (x& < 0) Or _
            (x& > UBound(bytPuzzle)) Or _
            (x& > UBound(bytPuzzleKey)) Then
            
            FitPuzzle = False
            
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
        If (bytPuzzle(x&) <> 32) And _
           (bytPuzzleKey(x&) <> 32) And _
           (bytPuzzle(x&) <> c&) Then
        
            FitPuzzle = False
            
            Exit Function
            
        End If
        
        x& = (x& + a&)
        
    Next i
    
    FitPuzzle = True
    
End Function

Public Sub PlacePuzzlePiece(ByVal s As String, ByVal x As Long, ByVal a As Long)

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i& = 1 To Len(s$)
    
        bytPuzzle(x&) = Asc(Mid(s$, i&, 1))
        bytPuzzleKey(x&) = Asc(Mid(s$, i&, 1))
        
        x& = (x& + a&)
        
    Next i
    
End Sub

Public Sub FillRestPuzzle()

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i& = 0 To UBound(bytPuzzle)
        If (bytPuzzle(i&) = 32) Then bytPuzzle(i&) = RandomLetter()
    Next i&
    
End Sub

Public Sub FillRestPuzzleBlank()

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i& = 0 To UBound(bytPuzzleKey)
        If bytPuzzleKey(i&) = 32 Then bytPuzzleKey(i&) = 32
    Next i&
    
End Sub

Public Function RandomLetter() As Byte

    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    c& = Int(Rnd * lngSumW&)
    
    Do
        c& = (c& - lngW(i&))
        If (c& < 0) Then Exit Do
        i& = (i& + 1)
    Loop
    
    Call Randomize(Timer)
    
    RandomLetter = (65 + (Rnd * i&))
    
End Function

Main:

  Call Randomize(Timer)

  Dim i As Long

  Dim v As Variant
    
  v = Array(368, 65, 124, 171, 591, 132, 90, 237, 286, 6, 19, 153, 114, 320, 360, 89, 5, 308, 275, 473, 111, 41, 68, 7, 89, 3)

  For i& = 0 To 25
     lngW(i&) = v(i&)
     lngSumW& = (lngSumW& + lngW(i&))
  Next i&

CreatePuzzle()

         Call FillRestPuzzle
         Call FillRestPuzzleBlank

         For i& = 0 To UBound(bytPuzzle)
              If bytPuzzle(i&) = 0 Then
                 b$ = (b$ + a$ + vbCrLf)
                 a$ = ""
              Else
                 a$ = (a$ + Chr$(bytPuzzle(i&)) + Chr$(32))
              End If
         Next i&

         For i& = 0 To (UBound(bytPuzzleKey))
              If bytPuzzleKey(i&) = 0 Then
                 d$ = (d$ + c$ + vbCrLf)
                 c$ = ""
              Else
                 c$ = (c$ + Chr$(bytPuzzleKey(i&)) + Chr$(32))
              End If
         Next i&

         txtPuzzle.Text = (b$ + a$)
         txtPuzzleKey.Text = (c$ + d$)
```